# AttributeError on type object using a Form within a Flask APP

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I keep getting an Attribute Error when I submit a form on my flask app

Here is my app.route:

[App.route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhqnb.png)

my form.py:

[SongForm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIoZy.png)

my error message:
[AttributeError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnjE8.png)

Comment: Hi Scott, could you please add source code and output as text instead of image links in your post?

Comment: in App.route, change the first line of code to `form = SongForm(request.form)`